# Navigation to a external URL while passing HttpPost parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

while extending a mvc website I got the requirement to call a external contact form and pass HttpPost parameter.

```
var httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var postData = CreatePostData();
var data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

using (var stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
var rStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

At this point I've got a response with a) different parameters like request URL in response and b) a raw html string from `httpWReq.GetRequestStream()` with the response page included. The hidden fields within the html string tell me, that my parameters got received correctly.

But how to continue now? If I redirect to the url the parameters are gone. If I return a ContentResult with the html string from the response as parameter, the site is shown but without css styling. The css is linked relative and the locally deployed mvc application is looking at `localhost:port/site.css` for the resource.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I think you're asking how to post data / html content to an external url from your MVC controller. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you manipulate the external site in anyway in terms of changing code?

Comment: No. The POST is done. As I wrote the response already includes the posted data as `hidden` field. The problem is, that if I navigate to that url after POST the parameters are not available (which is obvious). And if I show the raw html from the response in browser, the css isn't loaded because of relative paths.

Comment: @heymega I could try the responsible developer and ask for a change. What would be your solution? A absolute css link?

Comment: @csteinmueller I'm guessing you just want to navigate to the external contact form with the values already inserted in the appropriate fields such as subject and message. If so, get the developer to check for post and get values such as ?subject=test&message=woo and then bind them to the relevant fields

Comment: The problem is, that it has to be a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I got another solution for my problem. For those who are interested:

I created another form within my razor template

```
<form action="external-url.com" name="form_contact" id="form_contact" 
      method="POST" target="blank">
```

with all my parameters as HtmlHelpers's `Html.Hidden`fields

```
@Html.Hidden("Parametername", Model.ParameterXy)
```

with a bound value from my model.

The form is submitted via JavaScript.

Greetings